# keras: using the output of one model as part of the inputs of another model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

lets say I trained a auto encoder (which gives me encoder1, decoder1 and autoencoder1 which is the oncatination of encoder1 and decoder1). this autoencoder had 3 latent nodes in the bottleneck.

now I would like to train another auto encoder (autoencoder 2). this new auto encoder has 6 nodes in the bottleneck. I would like to use encoder1 to create 3 of the input nodes of autoencoder2, and decoder 1 on the other hand, like this:
[image]

as you can see, there are 2 inputs and two outputs, each with its own loss. e1 and d1 are built and I want to construct auto encoder 2 that contains all: e1, e2, d1, d2.

now, if it was just joining them together with 1 input and output, I would know how to do it:

```
autoencoder2 = Model(inputs=input, ouptuts=d1(d2(e2(e1(input)))))
```

but since there are two inputs, I dont know to to do this. I went through the functional api documentation, but couldent find what i need. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Tuples:

```
model = Model(inputs=(e1, e2), outputs=(o1, o2))
```

The only requirement is in your forward function that should accept and handle the tuples.

Comment: ty! what do you mean by "forward function"?

Comment: In Keras it is the `call()` method, `forward` is the PyTorch one. It's a method you implement when creating a new layer or model on your own.